# Excel, change format of a date, then make ALL cells in column look the new way

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a file where the date column is in a format I cannot make calculations, so I changed the column to another format where I can subtract dates. As usually happens with excel though, only when I double click an entry it changes to the new format.

Does anyone know how I can force all the cells in column to change to the new format, in order for my script to be able to subtract dates for the whole file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: How to force cell evaluation](http://superuser.com/questions/299437/excel-how-to-force-cell-evaluation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your vbScript

```
objExcel.Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat = "#0.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really easy work-around:

1. Insert a blank column.
2. Change the format of the blank column to the date format that you want.
3. Copy the column with the dates that won't format.
4. Right-click on the first cell of the blank, formatted column, select Paste Special, select Paste:Values and Operation:Add. (Because the destination cells are blank, the dates will be unchanged.) Click OK.
5. The dates will now appear as dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do this via VBA, you can use something like this:

```
Range("C1:C100").NumberFormat = Range("B2").NumberFormat
```

The example above just changes the format for cells C1-C100 to whatever the format is in B2.

**Update**:
I noticed you said that the format is working fine, but dispalys as #######. This typically happens when the column is not wide enough to show the whole value, so resizing it manually or using something like the belwo should fix your issue:

```
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: its an one time thing, just to make my current script run, so I would go with this paintbrush tool. Nonetheless, I cant find it in my excel(its mac 2011). Can you tell me exactly where I can find it?

Comment: Nonetheless, it doesnt seem to work. I believe this is happening because the correct format is alreasy set for all cells, but their appearance only changes if I double click on them.

Comment: I updated my answer with a VBA solution. I have tested and it will update all the cells in the range when you call this.

Comment: This piece of code changes the format indeed, but I have figured out that this is not my problem after all. All the cells have the correct format already, but they dont appear according to this format!! Think about it as the common issue when number or dates show up as ######## and you have to double click them in order to see the actual value.

Comment: Typically ####### is shown when the column is just simply too narrow to show the full length of the value. You can add soemthing like "Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit" and that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try `=Datevalue()` in an adjacent column. My experience in these types of situation is that Excel doesn't understand that your entries are dates. They are text, and will not change to date simply on a format change. Alternatively you can try text to columns to do the conversion.